# Can you cache the results of a subquery that's used repeatedly in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a series of queries being `UNION`'d together. Each query has a `WHERE... IN` clause that compares against the same list of IDs.

In a simplified form for example purposes it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE AuthorUserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE TeamId = @teamId)

UNION

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE PublisherUserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM USERS WHERE TeamId = @teamId)

UNION...
```

and so on. `@teamId` is an int stored procedure parameter.

Is there a way to tell SQL Server to hold on to the result set of

```
SELECT UserId FROM USERS WHERE TeamId = @teamId
```

so it doesn't fetch it for each `SELECT`?

Comment: you could insert into a temporary table and then query against that... or you could hope that the results of the subquery gets into the general query cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do this is by capturing the results of that query and storing it in a temp table, and `JOIN`ing to those results in your query:

```
Declare @UserIds Table (UserId Int)

Insert  @UserIds (UserId)
SELECT  UserId 
FROM    Users 
WHERE   TeamId = @teamId

SELECT  M.* 
FROM    MyTable     M
JOIN    @UserIds    U   ON  M.AuthorUserId = U.UserId

UNION

SELECT  M.* 
FROM    MyTable     M
JOIN    @UserIds    U   ON  M.PublisherUserId = U.UserId

UNION...
```

Comment: I know it looks like you could remove the `UNION`s from the example, but that's just cause I simplified it so much from the original.

Comment: @Legion I kinda figured - wasn't too sure so I thought I'd throw it in there just in case.

Comment: You're showing a TABLE variable, not a temporary table. There are quite a few differences, one of them being that queries against a TABLE variable are usually slower. See [What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/65699) for an exhaustive list of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server is smart enough to store results of same query if the parameters are same. If your subquery is not using session variables, you will be fine. You can also put index on TeamId which will make this query faster.

If you are still worried about it and using any programming language to get data from SP, then you should store it in a variable in code and then pass that result set into SP.

Second option would be to store it in temp table and then query it from temp table